# Undeclared identifier _setTokenURI in ERC721

Tags: solidity, truffle, erc-721

I'm using

> pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

I heard that _setTokenURI was removed in pragma 0.8.0

I tried these options
https://forum.openzeppelin.com/t/function-settokenuri-in-erc721-is-gone-with-pragma-0-8-0/5978

like using

> import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";

but that didn't work either, has anyone else figured out a work around for this ?

Strange they still have it in their docs https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/erc721

Code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";

contract myNFT is ERC721{

    using Counters for Counters.Counter;
    Counters.Counter private _tokenIds;
        mapping(string => uint8) hashes;

    constructor() public ERC721("myNFT", "MNFT") {}

    function awardItem(address recipient, string memory hash, string memory metadata)
        public
        returns (uint256)
    {
        require(hashes[hash] != 1);     
        hashes[hash] = 1;
        _tokenIds.increment();
        uint256 newItemId = _tokenIds.current();
        _mint(recipient, newItemId);
        _setTokenURI(newItemId, metadata);

        return newItemId;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you are right, the function `_setTokenURI()` was removed in `pragma 0.8.0;` and you have imported the updated `ERC721URIStorage.sol`.

But, you need to use that in your smart contract by using inheritance. So, you have to inherit `ERC721URIStorage` not `ERC721`.

```
contract myNFT is ERC721URIStorage{
              
}
```

hope this help you!!

Answer (score 2):

```
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
```

and then inherit the contract with ERC721URIStorage

```
contract myNFT is ERC721URIStorage{
              
}
```

hope this will work